Get product description in different languages using Shopify REST API
How to retrieve product details (title, description) in a language other than the default via Shopify REST API?
I tried adding a header:
 $requests = $shop->api()->rest('GET', 'admin/api/2024-04/products/' . $request->id . '.json', [
    'fields' => 'id,title,body_html',
], $options = [
   'Content-Language' => 'es',
   'Accept-Language' => 'es',
    
        ]);

but that doesn't work, return data in the default language. Any ideas?
If I run something like https://example.myshopify.com/es/products/vans-authentic-lo-pro-burgandy-white.json then I get the correct language. Also there is no any docs available...

Should work this way, according to https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/get-product-details-in-different-language-using-rest-api/td-p/2586604 (that might even be your question there, I'm guessing?) It might be that es is not specific enough though - there are different "versions" of Spanish spoken around the world, f.e. in Spain vs Latin America. So it could be that you have to specify the region as well, for example something like es-ES?
